# C Double Typecast

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Here's this code from the Art of Exploitation book by Jon Erikson.  I understand the typecast on the second line makes the compiler leave you alone about data types.  What I'm not sure about is why double typecasting is necessary on the bottom line.

```
int *int_pointer;  
int_pointer = (int *) char_array;

for(i=0; i < 5; i++) 
    printf("[integer pointer] points to %p, which contains the char '%c'\n", int_pointer, *int_pointer);
    int_pointer = (int *) ((char *) int_pointer + 1);
```

I am going to assume it's because leaving it like so without the `(int *)` would make it increment by the correct data type character, but is this not what you want?  Why typecast back to int?

And what's up with the `*` inside the parenthesis?  Is this de-referencing the data in the variable?  Some explanation would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: In case you are unaware, this may cause undefined behaviour if the system has alignment requirements for `int`.

Comment: @Matt, technically it causes UB no matter what. It's just that UB is a proper superset of "does what you expect" :-)

Comment: Implicitly converting `char *` to `int *` can cause compiler warnings, but explicit conversion doesn't. This code is the most annoying kind of UB because when you turn on O3 optimization, compiler will stop issuing non-aligned load/store instructions. When you find "crap it only works with O0", you are already deep in the hole.

Comment: @paxdiablo why does it cause UB no matter what?

Comment: @Matt, just saying that when ISO C states that doing something is UB, it's UB. The _effects_ may be benign but what you're doing is still UB. However, on reading the _actual_ controlling part `If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is
undefined`, I'm wrong in this case (apologies on my part). ISO states it's only UB if alignment is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not typecasting to `int` or `char`, it's typecasting the *pointer* to a `char` pointer or `int` pointer.

When you add one to a pointer, it advances to the next *item* being pointed at, by scaling the increment based on the type of the item.

If the items are `int`, it advances by the size of an `int`. This is probably 4 or 8 in the current environment but will hopefully will be larger in future so we can stop messing about with bignum libraries :-)

If the items are of type `char`, it advances by one (`sizeof(char)` is *always* one, since ISO C defines a byte as the size of a `char` rather than eight bits).

So, if you have four-byte `int` types, there's a big difference between advancing an `int` pointer and a `char` pointer. For example, consider the following code:

```
int *p = 0;                 // bad idea but shows the concept.
p = p + 1;                  // p is now 4.
p = (int*)(((char*)p) + 1)  // p is now 5.
```

That last statement breaks down as:

```
(char*)p - get a char pointer version of p (a)
a + 1    - add one to it (b)
(int*)b  - cast it back to an int pointer (c)
p = c    - replace p with that value
```

Comment: Maybe this is terribly obvious, but I fail to see why typecasting back to int is necessary.  Is this because you can't add character data to p because it is inherently declared as an int pointer?  And are the asterix within parenthesis because it's typecasting pointers?

Comment: @WhiteMask, the cast back to `int *` is necessary because that's the type of `int_pointer`. Conversion between pointer types (except to/from `void *`) requires an explicit cast in C. The asterisks are there because the conversions are between pointer types, yes - from `int *` to `char *` and then back to `int *`.

Comment: @WhiteMask, last one first: yes. It's typecasting pointers. On the first question, I'd do that just to be explicit. The standard mandates that you can convert to/from void* implicitly but I'm not that certain on other pointer types. I know gcc issues a warning for it so it's possibly not considered an error. Given you may already be well into UB by dereferencing misaligned pointers, it probably doesn't matter :-) UB is probably not a problem here given your intent is exploitation anyway since you need a solid understanding of how things work in a given implementation.

Comment: Dereferencing misaligned pointers isn't UB is it? Just implementation-specified? I certainly can't remember.

Comment: @Carl, as per ISO C11 `6.3.2.3/7`: `A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.` So, not _always_ UB but possible. Certainly non-portable but, given the domain we're examining, that probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @paxdiablo Slightly off-topic, how do you interpret that rule you listed. Does just the assignment of a pointer to a pointer of a different type that is not correctly aligned cause UB ( No dereferencing is done in this case ) ?

Comment: @2501, that's a _very_ good question. Normally I wouldn't expect trouble until you dereference but, from the "language lawyer" reading of the standard, the conversion itself seems problematic. That's actually worthy of a new question, I suspect.

Comment: @paxdiablo I had this debate on SO already( in comments only ), unfortunately there was no agreement.

Comment: @paxdiablo https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/EXP36-C.+Do+not+cast+pointers+into+more+strictly+aligned+pointer+types Seems to agree that the assignment itself will cause UB. Do you think it is worthwhile to post a question->answer combo on this?

Comment: @2501, yes I think so, provided it hasn't yet been asked.